# Воспроизведение аудио, независимо от смены сцен Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

При каждой загрузке сцены Audio Source воспроизводится заново. Отключение Play on Awake и воспроизведение через `audio.Play()` тоже не приносит успехов, т.к. очевидно, что всё завязано на объектах сцены, которая при загрузке всё сбрасывает заново.

Как можно воспроизводить аудио беспрерывно, независимо от смены сцен?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо поместить воспроизведение звука на отдельный GameObject и пометить его как не уничтожаемый при смене сцен с помощью DontDestroyOnLoad(this); например в Awake(). Так как GameObject не будет уничтожаться воспроизведение звука прерываться не будет